# Session is not loading while a cluster goes down in jboss standalone application?

Tags: java, spring, jboss

I am  facing and issue in **jboss** standalone application in cluster environment. I have two node and i am using **mod_cluster** for load balancing. node 1 name is **imran-pc** and node 2 name is **osama-pc**. this is log when a cluster is goes down or shutdown:

> 16:44:39,223 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.impl.CoreGroupCommunicationService.web] (VERIFY_SUSPECT.TimerThread,web,imran-pc/web) JBAS010254: Suspected member: osama-pc/web
>   16:44:39,326 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.impl.CoreGroupCommunicationService.lifecycle.web] (Incoming-3,null) JBAS010247: New cluster view for partition web (id: 4, delta: -1, merge: false) : [imran-pc/web]
>   16:44:39,327 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (Incoming-3,null) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view: [imran-pc/web|4] [imran-pc/web]

after this when i goes on my html page the following exception occurs:

> 16:44:58,693 WARN  [org.jboss.as.clustering.web.infinispan] (ajp--192.168.0.148-8009-2) JBAS010322: Failed to load session +Up723Rj0MQ8+vQ7ChdKdyyy: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS010333: Failed to load session attributes for session: +Up723Rj0MQ8+vQ7ChdKdyyy
>       at org.jboss.as.clustering.web.infinispan.DistributedCacheManager$2.invoke(DistributedCacheManager.java:223)
>       at org.jboss.as.clustering.web.infinispan.DistributedCacheManager$2.invoke(DistributedCacheManager.java:206)
>       at org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.invoker.RetryingCacheInvoker.invoke(RetryingCacheInvoker.java:60)
>       at org.jboss.as.clustering.web.infinispan.DistributedCacheManager$ForceSynchronousCacheInvoker.invoke(DistributedCacheManager.java:518)
>       at org.jboss.as.clustering.web.infinispan.DistributedCacheManager.invoke(DistributedCacheManager.java:486)
>       at org.jboss.as.clustering.web.infinispan.DistributedCacheManager.getData(DistributedCacheManager.java:232)
>       at org.jboss.as.clustering.web.infinispan.DistributedCacheManager.getSessionData(DistributedCacheManager.java:190)
>       at org.jboss.as.web.session.DistributableSessionManager.loadSession(DistributableSessionManager.java:1390) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
>       at org.jboss.as.web.session.DistributableSessionManager.findSession(DistributableSessionManager.java:686) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
>       at org.jboss.as.web.session.DistributableSessionManager.findSession(DistributableSessionManager.java:85) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2618) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2375) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:81) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:505) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:445) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_27]
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tabs.bcrs.common.UserSesionBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$38d509db from [Module "deployment.WEB-BCRS-VEH.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_27]
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247) [rt.jar:1.6.0_27]
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.ModularClassResolver.resolveClass(ModularClassResolver.java:106)
>       at org.jboss.as.clustering.ClassLoaderAwareClassResolver.resolveClass(ClassLoaderAwareClassResolver.java:92)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadClassDescriptor(RiverUnmarshaller.java:892)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1204)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:272)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:209)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readFields(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1677)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1593)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1557)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1235)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:272)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:209)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readFields(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1677)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1593)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1235)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:272)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:209)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readFields(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1677)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1593)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1235)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:272)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:209)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadMapObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:195)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readMapData(RiverUnmarshaller.java:793)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:682)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:209)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:37)
>       at org.jboss.as.clustering.SimpleMarshalledValue.get(SimpleMarshalledValue.java:108)
>       at org.jboss.as.clustering.web.impl.SessionAttributeMarshallerImpl.unmarshal(SessionAttributeMarshallerImpl.java:72)
>       at org.jboss.as.clustering.web.infinispan.CoarseSessionAttributeStorage.load(CoarseSessionAttributeStorage.java:64)
>       at org.jboss.as.clustering.web.infinispan.DistributedCacheManager$2.invoke(DistributedCacheManager.java:221)
>       ... 20 more

It is not merging my sessions. i don't know why this error is occuring. 
I am using **spring security** and i check my **usersessionbean** is also adding in **sessionRegistory**. Why this exception is occuring? is it because of **Jboss configuration**? **mod_cluster** configuration or issue persist in my application?